# How to view media files recursively with subfolder in gthumb

Tags: image-viewers, gthumb

If I click some folder or Catalog, I want to see all the photos and videos. So the media from the subfolder should be in my Browser View.

Is this possible?

Comment: This feature is not yet implemented, discussion [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/-/issues/218). You could use [Shotwell](https://shotwell-project.org/doc/html/) instead, which allows importing the images of a directory recursively and then shows all images in a gallery.